# Percentile in groupby with named aggregation pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Percentile in groupby with named aggregation

Function to calculate percentile:'

```
def percentile(n):
    def percentile_(x):
        return np.percentile(x, n)
    percentile_.__name__ = 'percentile_%s' % n
    return percentile_
```

percentile(25) gives value of 25th percentile otherwise.

df columns are as below:

```
  Key1   Key2   Col1   Col2
```

Code written by me to get mean, median of Col1 and count of Col2 and percentiles for Col1:

```
def params_calculate: 
    df2 = (df.groupby(["Key1", "Key2"])
             .agg(Mean=("Col1", 'mean'),
                  Median=('Col1','median'),
                  Count = ('Col2', 'count'),
                  Twentyfive_percentile = ('Col1',percentile(25),
                  Seventyfive_percentile = ('Col1',percentile(75))
   return df2
```

Output

```
  Key1   Key 2   Mean    Median   Count   Twentyfive_percentile    Seventyfive_percentile 
  2010    Jan     12       4       22         NAN                      NAN
  2010    Feb     10       3       20         NAN                      NAN
  2010    Mar     2        5       23         NAN                      NAN
  2010    Apr     22       4       21         NAN                      NAN
  2010    Jun     11       2       24         NAN                      NAN
  2010    Jul     34       1       32         NAN                      NAN
```

I want the twenty fifth and 75th percentile in the groupby output on key 1 and key 2 (year and month)
This is giving me NAN values.

Edit:

Also after I use percentile() inside another function params_calculate the next line after implementing percentile(25) is giving an error,(I have not mentioned next line here,  but lets say it is print something so that next line is giving error if I type percentile. If I dont type percentile then there is no error. So is it even possible to return percentile value in a function which already returns something?

Comment: What was error? last 3 lines of error.

Comment: No error. Just NAN values

Comment: For me it working nice with sample data :(

Comment: The error is not in the percentile line. But after this function params_calculate is over , the next line after the function is giving error

Comment: Not sure if understand, problem is in some another code? Because I test your solution from question with data from question and for me working perfectly.

Comment: See def params_calculate is working with no error for me by giving nan values. If I include percentile values, the next line of code(outside function) gives error. However if I dont include percentile , then next line does not give error.

Comment: What is error in next line?

Comment: Now im not getting any error. Only nan in percentile column. May be there is some issue with my approach. Let me try wth dummy data too first